# How to insert tables in README.md of vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, doc, readme

I want to insert tables in `README.md` for a `vscode` extension. My codes are as following:

```
* some title

  | words              | transform to | keepUpperCase is false | keepUpperCase is true |  
  |--------------------|--------------|------------------------|-----------------------|  
  | "XML HTTP request" | pascalCase   | `XmlHttpRequest`       | `XMLHTTPRequest`      |  
  | "new customer ID"  | camelCase    | `newCustomerId`        | `newCustomerID`       |
```

The result in `github` and visual studio marketplace overview is as expected, but in extension overview opened by `vscode` is as following:

- some title

  | words | transform to | keepUpperCase is false | keepUpperCase is true |
  |--------------------|--------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
  | "XML HTTP request" | pascalCase | `XmlHttpRequest` | `XMLHTTPRequest` |
  | "new customer ID" | camelCase | `newCustomerId` | `newCustomerID` |

When I change my codes as following:

```
* some title

| words              | transform to | keepUpperCase is false | keepUpperCase is true |  
|--------------------|--------------|------------------------|-----------------------|  
| "XML HTTP request" | pascalCase   | `XmlHttpRequest`       | `XMLHTTPRequest`      |  
| "new customer ID"  | camelCase    | `newCustomerId`        | `newCustomerID`       |
```

The table is rendered as expected. But I will lost the document hierarchy this way.

Comment: “The table rendered as expected” sounds like you answered the question. What does “losing the document hierarchy” mean to you?

Comment: @  soulshined I mean, the latter codes can render normal tables, but no indent. I want indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with inline html:

```
* some title

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>words</th>
        <th>transform to</th>
        <th>keepUpperCase is false</th>
        <th>keepUpperCase is true</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>"XML HTTP request"</td>
            <td>pascalCase</td>
            <td><code>XmlHttpRequest</code></td>
            <td><code>XMLHTTPRequest</code></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>"new customer ID"</td>
            <td>camelCase</td>
            <td><code>newCustomerId</code></td>
            <td><code>newCustomerID</code></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different flavors of Markdown and each one can render differently.

The built-in Markdown engine of Visual Studio Code uses the [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) Markdown specification as mentioned in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_does-vs-code-support-github-flavored-markdown:

> Does VS Code support GitHub Flavored Markdown?
>
> No, VS Code targets the [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) Markdown specification using the [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) library. GitHub is moving toward the CommonMark specification which you can
>   read about in this [update](https://githubengineering.com/a-formal-spec-for-github-markdown).

As mentioned in [Extending the Markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_extending-the-markdown-preview), if you are targeting a specific platform (Github in your case), you can install an extension that changes the built-in markdown preview to match the target platform's styling. For example, you can install the suggested [Markdown Preview Github Styling](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles) so that your preview will look the same as the one in Github.